# Write a function takes in 2 parameters – the pointer head OR tail plus the direction to traverse for a linked list

Tags: c++, function, linked-list, traversal

Here is how I defined and initialized a linked list

```
struct listrec
{
    struct listrec    *prev;
    float       value;
    struct listrec    *next;
};

listrec *head, *tail;

int main() {
int number;
cin >> number;
float content = 2.0;
    for (float i = 0; i < number; i++)
    {
        if (i == 0)
        {
            head = new listrec;
            head->prev = nullptr;
            head->value = 1.0;
            head->next = nullptr;
            tail = head;
        }
        else
        {
            auto *newNode = new listrec;
            newNode->value = content++;
            newNode->next = nullptr;
            newNode->prev = tail;
            tail->next = newNode;
            tail = tail->next;
        }
    }
return 0;
}
```

This is how the linked list looks like

[image]

I need to " **write a function that takes two input parameters - the pointer head OR tail plus a parameter of which direction to traverse - to traverse the linked list and return the number of elements in the list.** "

I have no idea how to write a function like that…

I know, if I want to count the number of elements from the first node, then I can write a function like this:

```
float listSize(listrec* head)
{
    int count = 0; 
    listrec* current = head; // Initialize current  
    while (current != NULL)
    {
        count++;
        current = current->next;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Or, if I want to count the elements from the last element, then

```
float listSize2(listrec* tail)
{
    int count = 1;
    listrec* current = tail;
    while (tail->prev != NULL)
    {
        count++;
        tail = tail->prev;
    }
    return count;
}
```

But how can I combine these two? Any hints would be appreciated!

Comment: The function does not make sense because the number of elements will be the same independent on in which direction the list is traversed. So the direction is senseless. Maybe the word "traverse" means  to output the list on console does it?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I know right, but once a while, you have to write some strange functions because it's your homework. Thomas Matthews' answer below actually solved this problem by using only one function, so definitely recommend to take a look at it  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the function, assuming a doubly linked list:

```
enum class Direction {FORWARD, REVERSE};

struct Node
{
    Node * previous;
    Node * next;
};

unsigned int Count(Node * p_begin, Direction traverse_dir)
{
    unsigned int node_count = 0U;
    while (p_begin != nullptr)
    {
        ++node_count;
        if (traverse_dir == FORWARD)
        {
            p_begin = p_begin->next;
        }
        else
        {
            p_begin = p_begin->previous;
        }
    }
    return node_count;
}
```

Per the requirement, the function takes 2 parameters, a pointer to a head or tail node, and a direction and returns the quantity of nodes traversed.

The function starts at the pointer passed, then goes forward or reverse (depending on the direction parameter), and increments the node counter.  The loop stops when a null pointer is encountered, which usually signals the beginning or end of a list.

Since only a node class is used, you can inherit from the Node to make various list types:

```
struct Integer_Node : public Node
{
    int data;
};
```

The data field does not play a role in traversing the list, so it was removed from the fundamental node object.

Comment: Hey Thomas, thank you for the answer! It worked! Just one little thing, can you change  "if (traverse_dir == FORWARD)" to "if (traverse_dir == Direction::FORWARD)", otherwise, the program won't recognize the word "FORWARD". Thank you!

Comment: So, what's my compensation for doing your homework?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to "combine" them. You need to call one or the other depending on the direction:

```
enum class Direction { Forward, Backwards };

int listSize(listrec* p, Direction dir)
{
     if (dir == Direction::Forward)
          return listSize(p);
     else
          return listSize2(p);
}
```

---

This is not a review site, that being said I cannot in good conscience leave this answer without some advice for your code:

- in C++ you should use [RAII](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/raii). A consequence of that is that you should never use explicit calls to `new` / `delete` and you should not use owning raw pointers.
- `count` is an integer, so returning `float` in your functions makes no sense. Floating point data has its problems, don't use it for integers.
- better name your functions. `listSize` and `listSize2` are terrible names. Your functions don't *list*, they just return the size. So a better name is `getSize`. Also differentiating between then by a number is another terrible idea. You can use `getSize` and `getSizeReverse`.
- there is no need to pass pointers to your function. Passing by reference, or even by value in your case is preferred.
- you need better OOP abstractions. `listrec` is a list record (aka a list node). On top of this you need a class that abstracts a list. This would contain a pointer to the head of the list and a pointer to the tail of the list.
- you should create a function for insertion into the list (and one for each operation on the list) and not do it manually in main.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions, these are definitely helpful! Didn't even thought about I can solve the problem in this way. Although this is kinda different than what the instruction was expected (only use one function to solve the problem) but your way works as well, and it's actually very beginner friendly. Thankss!